# Undefined columns seleted error in caret for SVM in Train

Tags: r

Need your help in solving the below error.

```
##Loading Libraries.
library(caret)
library(kernlab)

##Loading the data
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(3421)

Extrapolation_Data <- read.table("./Data/Data5/EP_CUST_COMBINED_07042017.txt",
                                sep="|", header=TRUE , 
                                colClasses = c("X6MNTH_FTD" = "NULL" , 
                                              "X6MNTH_LTD"="NULL" , 
                                              "India3MLtd_TRANS" = "NULL", 
                                              "Cust_Considered" = "NULL",
                                              "Customer_No"="character",
                                              "Segment"="factor",
                                              "Store"="factor",
                                              "DISTINCT_VISITS_BAND"="factor",
                                              "DISTINCT_MONTH_VISITS"="factor",
                                              "CUST_SALES_BAND"="factor",
                                              "ITEMS_PER_MONTH_BAND"="factor",
                                              "VISITS_PER_MONTH_BAND"="factor",
                                              "STAPLES_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "BDF_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "HPC_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PF_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "FV_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PROCESS_FOOD_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "BREAD_EGGS_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "FROZEN_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "MILK_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "LAUNDRY_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PC_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "DISTINCT_CLASSES_BAND"="factor",
                                              "LAUNDRY_TRANS_1"="factor",
                                              "Cookies_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ExoticFruitandVegetables_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Healthbiscuit_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Kellogs_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "BasmatiRice_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Pastry_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Dessert_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Organics_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PaperandTissue_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Almonds_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Pears_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "GingellyOil_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Yoghurt_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Dove_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Mayonnaise_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PeanutButter_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "HealthDietFood_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "OliveOil_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ShowerGel_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ChocolateSpread_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Continental_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "GarbageBag_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ReadytoEat_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ToiletPaper_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "MOP_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "IceTea_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ShowerandBath_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "CarCare_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PetFood_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Muesli_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "CottonBall_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "CannedFood_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PremiumVegetables_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Maybelline_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "PremixCoffee_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "ImportedCigarettes_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "MicrowaveItems_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Housekeeping.Plugin_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "YogaMat_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Moti_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Toys_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Loreal_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "AdultsBooks_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Gala_TRANS"="factor",
                                              "Revlon_TRANS"="factor"))

## Dividing the data in Train Test.    
indexes = sample(nrow(Extrapolation_Data), 
                 size=0.2*nrow(Extrapolation_Data), replace= FALSE)
TrainData <- Extrapolation_Data[-indexes,]
TestData <- Extrapolation_Data[indexes,]    

##Creating new column Segment_C from Segment
TrainData$Segment_C <- as.factor(ifelse(TrainData$Segment=="C", "Y" , "N"))
TestData$Segment_C <- as.factor(ifelse(TestData$Segment=="C", "Y" , "N"))

## No Null Values
sum(is.na(TrainData))
# [1] 0

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 1,repeats = 2,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)    
set.seed(10001)

## Executing the below query is giving me error    
SVMFit <- train(Segment_C ~ TENURE + CUST_SALES + VISITS_PER_MONTH + FROZEN_TRANS + 
                          MILK_TRANS + PC_TRANS + Cookies_TRANS,  
                data=TrainData, method="lssvmPoly", 
                trControl = fitControl , metric = "Kappa")
```

Error:

> Error in [.data.frame(data, , lvls[1]) : undefined columns selected

Am I missing anything? Is any of my variables incorrect?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Update code formatting, title, error message, and grammar for readability

Comment: looks like you are missing "_BAND" from "CUST_SALES" and "VISITS_PER_MONTH", which both should have the "_BAND" suffix, based on your read-in code.

Comment: SVMFit<-train(Segment_C~MILK_TRANS, data=TrainData, method="lssvmPoly" , trControl = fitControl , metric = "Kappa") Even this is giving me same error

Answer (score 0):

The variable names are incorrectly defined in the below statement--
SVMFit<-train(Segment_C~TENURE+CUST_SALES+VISITS_PER_MONTH+FROZEN_TRANS+MILK_TRANS+PC_TRANS+Cookies_TRANS,  data=TrainData, method="lssvmPoly" , trControl = fitControl , metric = "Kappa")

The original data does not contains the var. named as "Tenure". 
As well as CUST_SALES,VISITS_PER_MONTH: Original variable names are CUST_SALES_BAND and VISITS_PER_MONTH_BAND

Comment: Take a look at names(Extrapolation_Data)  Customer_No
Store
DISTINCT_VISITS_BAND
CUST_SALES
RECENCY
TOTAL_ITEMS
ITEMS_PER_MONTH_BAND
VISITS_PER_MONTH_BAND
BDF_TRANS
PF_TRANS
PROCESS_FOOD_TRANS
FROZEN_TRANS
LAUNDRY_TRANS
DISTINCT_ITEMS
DISTINCT_CLASSES_BAND
DISTINCT_DEPTS
LAUNDRY_TRANS_1
ExoticFruitandVegetables_TRANS
Kellogs_TRANS
Pastry_TRANS
Organics_TRANS
Almonds_TRANS
GingellyOil_TRANS
Dove_TRANS
PeanutButter_TRANS
OliveOil_TRANS
ChocolateSpread_TRANS
GarbageBag_TRANS
ToiletPaper_TRANS
IceTea_TRANS
CarCare_TRANS
Muesli_TRANS
CannedFood_TRANS

Comment: Maybelline_TRANS
ImportedCigarettes_TRANS
Housekeeping.Plugin_TRANS
Moti_TRANS
Loreal_TRANS
Gala_TRANS
Segment
DISTINCT_VISITS
DISTINCT_MONTH_VISITS
CUST_SALES_BAND
TENURE
ITEMS_PER_MONTH
VISITS_PER_MONTH
STAPLES_TRANS
HPC_TRANS
FV_TRANS
BREAD_EGGS_TRANS
MILK_TRANS
PC_TRANS
DISTINCT_CLASSES
DISTINCT_SUBCLASSES
DISTINCT_DIVISIONS
Cookies_TRANS
Healthbiscuit_TRANS
BasmatiRice_TRANS
Dessert_TRANS
PaperandTissue_TRANS
Pears_TRANS
Yoghurt_TRANS
Mayonnaise_TRANS
HealthDietFood_TRANS
ShowerGel_TRANS
Continental_TRANS
ReadytoEat_TRANS
MOP_TRANS
ShowerandBath_TRANS

Comment: PetFood_TRANS
CottonBall_TRANS
PremiumVegetables_TRANS
PremixCoffee_TRANS
MicrowaveItems_TRANS
YogaMat_TRANS
Toys_TRANS
AdultsBooks_TRANS
Revlon_TRANS

Comment: SVMFit<-train(Segment_C~MILK_TRANS,  data=TrainData, method="lssvmPoly" , trControl = fitControl , metric = "Kappa") Even this is giving me same error